# Jest TypeScript: extended type does not exist on type T

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am testing the creation of a new ticket entity with Jest in my Node/TS project. The types for a ticket are provided below:

```
export interface Entity {
    getId: () => string;
    getTitle: () => string;
}

export interface Ticket extends Entity {
    getDetails: () => string;
    getCategory: () => CategoryOptions;
    getStatus: () => StatusOptions;
    getCreatedAt: () => Date;
    getUpdatedAt: () => Date;
}
```

As you can see, the Ticket extends the props of a generic Entity type. There are no type errors in my actual code, but inside my test suite, I am trying:

```
it("should create new ticket entity", () => {
    const ticket: Ticket = makeTicket(ticketInfo);

    expect(ticket.getId()).toBe("1234567890");

});
```

which outputs the following type error

> Property 'getId' does not exist on type 'Ticket'. ts(2339)

Here is my `babel.config.ts` file:

```
export default {
    // Stop running tests after `n` failures
    bail: 3,

    // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
    clearMocks: true,

    // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
    collectCoverage: true,

    // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
    coverageDirectory: "coverage",

    // An array of regexp pattern strings used to skip coverage collection
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/"
    ],

    // Indicates which provider should be used to instrument code for coverage
    coverageProvider: "v8",

    // A list of reporter names that Jest uses when writing coverage reports
    coverageReporters: [
        "json",
        "html",
        "text"
    ],

    // An object that configures minimum threshold enforcement for coverage results
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 80,
            functions: 80,
            lines: 80,
            statements: -10
        }
    },

    // An array of file extensions your modules use
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "js",
        "ts"
    ],

    // A preset that is used as a base for Jest's configuration
    preset: "ts-jest",

    // The root directory that Jest should scan for tests and modules within
    rootDir: ".",

    // A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in
    roots: [
        "<rootDir>/src"
    ],

    // The test environment that will be used for testing
    testEnvironment: "node",

    // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
    testMatch: [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
    ],

    // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/",
        "/api/",
        "/config/"
    ],
};
```

And my relevant `package.json` dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.13.10",
        "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
        "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
        "typescript": "^4.1.4",
    }
```

**Any ideas on how to ensure that Jest can read the types of ancestor types?**

Comment: Try not to use explicit types in test files.